# Will new session with same name replace previous?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

So if i have such code in action for `show` method:

```
session[:was_going]=object_url
```

And user can view several object, will these new session replace previous?

Comment: yes, it will replace the previous value contained in `session[:was_goind]`

Comment: How *couldn't* it replace it?

Comment: it is not so obvious. It could abort saving these cookie if another with same name is present. Anyway, I'd like to be sure before do something

Comment: you can use a hash, or an array for your session, if you don´t want that it get replaced..e.g session[:was_goind] = []. session[:was_goind] << something..